# Is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx$ equal to $- \int_{b}^{a} f(x)\,dx$?

Tags: integration

Is the following equality correct?

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx = - \int_{b}^{a} f(x)\,dx.$$

I think I have already seen it before (I don't remember exactly where), but I can't find nothing about it in the internet. If the answer is yes, can you show the proof?

Comment: It's correct. You can infer it, I think, from the identity $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_a^cf(x)\,dx+\int_c^bf(x)\,dx.$

Comment: That's true. How you prove it depends on how you defined the definite integral and what things you have already proved based on that definition.

Comment: @PeterForeman You don't need the FTC to prove that identity about definite integrals.